# Using Postgresql stored function as a data source in Power BI

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, stored-functions, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to use a stored function I have written in Postgresql as a data source for a Power BI chart.
The function accepts four parameters all of date type. The function signature looks like this:

`get_revenue_metrics(signup_start_date, signup_end_date, revenue_start_date, revenue_end_date)`

This function uses these dates in multiple where clauses to create and return a table. I want to use that table to then build charts in my dashboard.

I did come across [this link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/SQL-Functions-in-Power-BI/m-p/235426#M104804) which talks about using a SQL function in Power BI, but it is for Azure SQL Server and not Postgresql. From the very first step as mentioned in the link before, I do not see any option to

> Select the sql function when you initially select your data sources.

Is there something I am missing?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The "table picker" is pretty simplistic, and for some objects you'll have to start with a SQL query. See [PostgreSQL - Connect using advanced options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/postgresql#connect-using-advanced-options)

Comment: Thanks! that helped. I do have an additional follow-up question though.. is there any way I can make this more dynamic? Like if I want to update the parameters to this stored function based on a filter or a slicer input to update the chart accordingly?

Comment: Yes.  In DirectQuery you can use Dynamic M query parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters

Comment: Thanks a lot @David! That really helped me out. I also found a video which I have linked in my own answer which helped me understand the concept of parameters!